# How to Integrate Kotlin Multiplatform Static libraries in xcode ios mobile

Tags: kotlin, cross-platform, static-libraries, kotlin-multiplatform

```
listOf(
    iosX64(),
    iosArm64(),
    iosSimulatorArm64()
).forEach {
    it.binaries.staticLib {
        baseName = "shared"
    }
}
```

The above code shared Module level build.gradle.kts
by executing ./gradlew build command it created libshared.a and libshared_api.h files
now i want to integrate the static libraries in xcode ios mobile project.. can any one help

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL24Q.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXSwu.png)

Added library files to the xcode project
Added .h file path in Header Search Paths
Added .a file path in Library Search Paths in xcode project Build Settings
Added .a file path in Link Binary With Libraries xcode project Build Phases

Comment: I imagine you add them just like you would any other library. What is the exact problem you are having after doing that?

Comment: import UIKit
import shared

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}


- Inside ViewController im not able to import the shared module "shared" is not found i want to import the shared module to access the shared code